# Not all code paths return a value, console.writeline

Tags: c#

I have just started doing the tasks on exercism.io and the first one is to make Hello World print out. When I have done it in the past, I just put Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!"); into the curly brackets. This time though I get an error saying not all code paths return a value.

The template for my code is different this time, it has

```
using System;
public static class HelloWorld
{
    public static string Hello()
```

What do these two lines actually mean and how comes Console.WriteLine doesn't play nice with them?

What's the difference between that one and

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
```

How comes the template doesn't have a namespace?

```
using System;

    public static class HelloWorld
{
    public static string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
```

}

is this the best way to implement "Hello, World" with this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do these two lines actually mean and how comes Console.WriteLine doesn't play nice with them?

`Console.WriteLine` doesn't return any data. It has the return data type of `void`.

Your first method signature is

```
public static string Hello()
```

Which means that the method does not take any parameters and returns a string. If your full method looks like this:

```
public static string Hello()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something");
}
```

You'll get your "Not all code paths return a value" error. This is because the method *is not returning a value*, even though you've told the compiler it should be.

> What's the difference between that one and [one which uses void]

Again, look at the signatures of the methods:

```
public static string Hello()
static void Main(string[] args)
```

The main difference you're interested in is one returns `string`, and the other returns `void`.

> How comes the template doesn't have a namespace?

That's a great question. It's up to how the website architectures their code process. My guess it that it wraps your code file in a namespace behind the scenes when you submit it.